# Pop up window, or separate screen n Js

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am making a clicker game, it is very simple, and mostly just a learning process, for me to learn JavaScript. I have added a "Shop" button, attempting to have a separate screen, or a popup, to make a Shop place, where the player can shop for power-ups, using their "clicks" to purchase them, then they can close out the shop, and continue with their game.

This is what i tried:
I already had this variable set:

```
...
shopMenu = false;
...
```

This is everything else:

```
// Shop Button
if (mouse.dist(shop) < 40) {
  shopColor = "firebrick";
  shopMenu = true;
  if (shopMenu == true) {
    // This area is what I need help on, I don't know how to make a separate screen, to pop up, for a "shop".
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a shop div element in your html like

```html
<div id="shop">
  <p>Welcome to the shop</p>
</div>
```

and in your styling, have it hidden by default

```css
#shop {
 display: none;
}
```

Then back in your javascript,

```js
if(shopMenu === true) {
  const shopElement = document.getElementById('shop');
  shopElement.style.display = 'block'
}
```